Reactive programming in R shiny inputs
My question relates to reactive expressions in R Shiny inputs. For instance, say my first user input is Country. I want my next input to be States of that country. In particular, if the user selects a different country, their second input will change correspondingly. Naturally the US and Canada have different states. How would I go about doing this? Thanks!
I have tried conditional statements to create a dependency between the second input and the first input. But this did not work. I am essentially looking for a way to bind the second input to the first input.

Can you show what you've tried.

@Limey This does help. But I was wondering what to do if I want to update the label of the input itself as a function of another input. For instance, corresponding to an input of the US for country, the next input will have the header "States". While for Canada, the header for the next input would be "Provinces". Essentially, I want the input label to be dynamic.

Read the online doc for updateSelectInput. Everything you need is there.

@Geometer in that case what you can do is use the updateSelectInput inside an observeEvent that reacts to the first input. If a user selects "Canada" in the first selectInput, than you update the label to "Provinces", if they select "USA", you update it to "States" etc
